# How to create files/folders in external storage that are accessible via USB?

Tags: android, file, usb, storage

I am using a Nexus 5 as test device for my first Android app. When I connect the phone to my PC via USB, it pops up in the explorer and I can access different files and folder on the devices (just as if the device would be an USB stick...).

I thought that these files and folders would represent the `External Storage` and every file/folder my app stores in `External Storage` would be accessible via USB as well.

While creating files/folder in `External Storage` in my app is no problem, these files are not visible in the files and folders that can be accessed via USB:

```
public static File getAppPuplicExternalStorageDir() {
    File appDir = null;

    try {
        appDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyApp");
        appDir.mkdirs();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    return appDir;
}


...
File noMediaFile = new File(getAppPuplicExternalStorageDir(), ".nomedia");
noMediaFile.createNewFile();
...
```

This code workes perfectly. I can test if the file exist, delete the file, create other files, etc. without any problem.

When I check the appDir it has the path `/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/`. Everything works fine, except that this folder is not visible via USB.

Is there a difference between the external storage and the files/folder that are visibel via USB? The user should be able to download the files to his PC. How can I manage to make my files visible via USB?

Comment: just try by changing getAppPuplicExternalStorageDir() to an other string path..

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain in more detail please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> these files are not visible in the files and folders that can be accessed via USB

They will be, once `MediaScannerConnection` has indexed them. You can use `scanFile()` on `MediaScannerConnection` to make that happen faster.

Also note that the user may need to use a "refresh" or "reload" option in their MTP client (e.g., Windows Explorer) to see the files, or possibly even unplug/re-plug in the device, as some MTP clients cache directory listings.

> When I check the appDir it has the path /storage/emulated/0/MyApp/. Everything works fine, except that this folder is not visible via USB.

That would be a `MyApp/` directory under the root of external storage, at least for phones. For tablets with secondary users, the `MyApp/` directory will be visible for the user when the user has logged into the tablet. The `storage/emulated/0/` path is dynamic, to route your app's code to write to the right spot.

Also, please try not to use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` and clutter up the user's external storage. If these are files that the user should be manipulating, try to put them in a location specified by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.